# I have been refused a visit Schengen visa for Germany. Does it affect any attempt to apply for Schengen visa next year

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

I have just been refused a visit Schengen visa from the German embassy in Pakistan. The reason given is I could not prove sufficient family ties to my home country. The intention of my visit other than holidays was to visit both of my parents who reside in Germany.  I am almost 40 years old and divorced with a daughter who lives with her mother.

Despite telling the visa officer that I see my daughter every week and have taken out an insurance policy in her name (submitting the relevant documents) it clearly didn’t help my case. Neither did the fact that my father is 81 years old, cant travel and that I haven’t seen him in five years.

The line of questioning was highly personal and something I wasn’t prepared for. Frankly I didn’t have any convincing answers and that is partly the reason I wanted to visit Germany.

I have a stable job and a property investment for which I furnished the requisite documented proof. I have decided not to file a remonstrance, since by the time it’s sorted out my holidays will be over and even if in the unlikely case I get a visa it wouldn’t serve any purpose. I might try again next year. 
However, I am concerned that the refusal will affect any further visa application that I might make for Schengen states in the coming years. Additionally, part of the reason for my visit was highly personal and would have allowed me to resolve some family issues as I mentioned earlier.

I understand why the German embassy would refuse my application but should I write them a letter clarifying my circumstances and highlighting the personal nature of the visit that I wasn’t allowed to make. The intention is not for a reversal of decision since I mentioned it won’t do me any good, but the off chance of improving my chances for a future application and partly to express how bureaucratic protocols can affect personal relations and deny one an opportunity for closure.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, Pakistan is a country with a high visa refusal rate and applications usually draw significant scrutiny. To succeed with a future application, you'll not only need documentation but will also have to be prepared to answer personal questions about your trip and your family situation.

Comment: Which boxes were checked on your refusal notice?

Comment: just one. Number 9

Comment: How does the fact that you haven't seen your father in 5 years prove your family ties? It seems to do the opposite.